# How to make applications in QtCreator use KDE oxygen theme?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, archlinux, kde-plasma

I'm aware that the reason it's not already doing this is because KDE uses Qt 4. Unfortunately, I'm using Archlinux, and when I install the KDE window manager, it automatically installs Qt 5. If anyone could tell me how to use Qt 4 on Archlinux, or any other workarounds, I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: I'm talking about applications compiled in qtcreator, I couldn't care less about how qtcreator itself looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt 4 is still available in the official extra repository, so just get it. Actually, you could even use the 32 bit version on 64 bit kernel.

```
sudo pacman -S qt4
```

or

```
sudo pacman -S lib32-qt4
```

then, you need to configure QtCreator to use that `/usr/bin/qmake-qt4`.

[image]

Comment: @user3466884: click on details.

Comment: Yes, even after clicking on details, it won't let me edit the text field.

Comment: It lets me add additional arguements by typing into the "Additional arguments" line edit.

Comment: After pressing the "Manage kits" buttons and switching the qt5 qmake file with the qt4 qmake file, my applications use the kde oxygen theme. Many thanks...

Comment: You need to use the Manage kits button to add new kits, and then you can select between the kits anytime. The profile and build modes are supplied by default, and there would be no point in changing them, hence the additional arguments.

Comment: I know I mentioned in my original post that I didn't care about qtcreator's theme, but is there any way I can change its theme to kde oxygen. Currently, in designer mode, it displays all the widgets with the GTK+ theme, or some other theme that isn't kde oxygen, but when it compiles, it uses the kde oxygen theme.